# Frame in a plot

Tags: plotting, frame

When adding a frame to the following plot, the negative values become above the x-axis:

```
Plot[Log[t], {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

How can the natural plot be maintained while using a frame?

Comment: What does "the negative values become above" mean? What do you mean by "natural plot"?

Comment: I meant the same without 'Frame->True' (negative values are below x-axis)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
Plot[Log[t], {t, 0, 1},
 FrameTicks -> {{All, None}, {None, All}},
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
ticksWithoutLabels = Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}];

ticksWithLabels = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}];

Plot[Log[t], {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> 
  {{Automatic, Automatic}, {ticksWithoutLabels, ticksWithLabels}}]
```

[image]